# Cloudkit + Core Data not synching

Tags: swift, core-data, uikit, cloudkit

I have a Core Data + Couldkit App where any changes made on other device is not synched. I had to call the fetch method again refresh the data. The changes are made on relationships of the Entities like adding an object to NSManagedObject relationship set. Then I fetch the objects with a predicate and then populate data in table view from the relationship(NSSet) alone.

Even when I add data in another view controller, The changes are not reflected in parent controller where I display the data that were added. I had to add a notification observer to make this work and fetch the data again.

I even added the necessary lines in AppDelegate,

```
let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "myappcontainername")
container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

The following are the CoreData logs after making a change,

```
CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate finishedAutomatedRequestWithResult:](2119): Finished request '<NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest: 0x6> -UUID' with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x> success: 1 madeChanges: 1 error: (null)
```

Which implies that my changes have been synched with the Cloudkit.

What else should I be doing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your container like this?

```
  let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: id)
    
  let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
    
   
  description?.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
  description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
  description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
```

Comment: Nope. I did use the boilerplate code just by checking the Tickbox for use cloud kit. I copied the same code from a sample provided by Apple, It works. Still figuring out what exactly went wrong in my code. How is this different from the boilerplate code present already?